# Jquery-animate question: how to constrain a DIV animation within another DIV?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I created a list and a **bullet** to follow the selected `<li>` item on **click**.

HTML code:

```
<div class="right">
<div id="bullet">&diams;</div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#link1">link1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#link2">link2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#link3">link3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#link4">link4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY code:

```
$('li').bind('click', function(e) {
    var offset = $(e.target).offset();
    $('#bullet').animate({'top':offset.top},600);
});
```

The problem is that everytime I load the page and click a link for the first time, the bullet comes from the top of the browser instead of animating from its `<div>` position to the selected link. After that first click, the animation between links works just fine.

Can you help me on this?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `position: relative;` on `.right`.

Absolute positioned elements (like an element that has an animated top property) always use the browser viewspace's top left corner as 0:0, unless they have a parent that has any position other than static. In that case, that parent's top left corner is 0:0.

Comment: Thanks for helping and especially thanks for your explanation & fast reply!

Answer (score 1):

set the container div `.right` to be `position:relative`.