# Animation within outer Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have old text inside a div. 
I want that text to fly out to the left, and new text to fly in from the right.

Problem: 
I don't want the new text to fly in from within the browser window,
but rather from within the containing div.

http://jsfiddle.net/cabezud/XuyUb/1/

FYI I'm using Jquery & jquery mobile.
I found this other question here:
[Jquery-animate question: how to constrain a DIV animation within another DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533571/jquery-animate-question-how-to-constrain-a-div-animation-within-another-div)
but simply setting the outer div to position:relative changes nothing.

Per comments, adding more detail (rather then just a link to jsfiddle).

```
<div class="outer">
<p class="inner">click me</p>
</div>
```

​
    var fruit = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges', 'kiwis'];
    var num = 0;

```
$('.outer').click(function(){
    next();
});

var next = function() {
num++;
$('.inner').animate({"right":"500%"},500, function() {
    $('.inner').text(fruit[num]).css({"right":"-500%"});
    $('.inner').animate({"right":"0%"},500);
});
};
```

Comment: jsFiddle is a great tool on this site but you also need to make your question more "self-contained".  Otherwise, when the jsFiddle site goes down, the question is useless.

Comment: what you are looking for is nothing else than a slider. just use instead of pictures divs with your content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to the .outer div

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XuyUb/2/)**.